# DISKPART "CLEAN" Command issue in MiniTool Partition Wizard with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-10

I have 1TB HDD with this partitions

1. ubuntu 49.65 GB
2. Tool & Study 30.91 Gb
3. Entertainment 405.07 GB
4. Data 445.74 GB

In Ubuntu 16.04 i can't play game with [PlayOnLinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/), so i decide to install windows (For Playing Games) as second boot (Dual boot)
but when i was trying to install windows 10 is displayed me such error like

> We couldn’t create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the Setup log files

For this i follow [this tutorial](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/asiasupp/2012/03/06/error-we-couldnt-create-a-new-partition-or-locate-an-existing-one-for-more-information-see-the-setup-log-files-when-you-try-to-install-windows-8-cp/)
after i when i restart leptop it displayed me only one disk that is fully unallocated.so i search "How to recover data after getting Clean by DISKPART"
i found MiniTool Partition Wizard.i try this and i get my lost data of this drive

- Tools & Study
- Entertainment
- Data

but for linux root partition it displayed me as multiple partition divided into 5.0 GB each one.
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLhTr.jpg)

So The Question is

> How Can I Recover this root partition ???

Please help ....

Comment: Windows 10 installer is well known to mess up multi-disk or multi partition setups - there's probably not much you can do. Might be worth trying a Linux-specific data recover tool: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: I tried  with DataRecovery but it's not Working

Answer (score 1):

I could recover the partition table using the following steps.

1. I booted using a ubuntu-live USB and opened the desktop environment.
2. I connected to internet and installed testdisk

> sudo apt-get install testdisk

3. Then I started testdisk and followed the menu.
4. Select disk >  select partition table type (i used the default 'Intel' partition type that the software detected > Select Analyse > Hit enter once more for for advance search > Deeper search >
5. The partitions are listed and the deleted partitions are indicated with letter D.
6. Select the parition/s that you want to recover with up and down arrow keys. Use left and right arrow keys to change the D to P (primary) or L (logical) and then select write
7. reboot

(Followed the testdisk demo from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3jbWfGePrqo)